# apache tiles template inside another template

Tags: templates, jakarta-ee, tiles

I've got a "t.base" view definition for all pages:

```
<definition name="t.base" template="/WEB-INF/tiles/base.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="SomeTitle"/>
</definition>
```

it's main attribute is `body` which has to be defined in each child template. Now I want to have a slider on the homepage which will be put directly into the body (to be as wide as the screen):

```
<definition name="t.homepage" extends="t.base">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/homepage.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="title" expression="lyricsBase : home of lyrics"/>
</definition>
```

All the rest of pages will have to be put inside a HTML container (adding some CSS styles) not to make it as wide as the screen (margins, etc). I want this container template to "override" the `body` tiles attibute:

```
<div class="container marketing">
    <div class="container">
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Example child view inside the container HTML tags:

```
<definition name="t.jukebox" extends="t.base">
    <put-attribute name="body">
        <definition template="/WEB-INF/tiles/container.jsp">
            <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/jukebox.jsp" />
        </definition>
    </put-attribute>
    <put-attribute name="title" expression="${jukebox.name} - lyricsBase"/>
</definition>
```

Anyway, this doesn't look good and I hope there is a better solution that will reduce configuration size and will give exactly the same effect. I'm trying to do a definition of this container:

```
<definition name="t.container" extends="t.base">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/container.jsp"/>
</definition>
```

which would be used by child templates. But I don't know how to configure it.

In other words, I'd like to achieve something like [Russian Matrioszka dolls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matryoshka_doll) with using the same attribute name on all levels. Just overriding the attribute. I'm used to the `decorator` pattern and this `composite view` is still abstract to me. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use definition inheritance, where `t.homepage` will be extension of `t.container`, and `t.container` will be extension of t.base. 
Even more - you can create inside of body attribute another slots and define its in childs definitions.